# Сформировать массив бинарного дерева

Tags: php

```
$massive = array(
    0 => array(
              "id" => 2,
              "parent" => 0
            ),
    1 => array(
              "id" => 3,
              "parent" => 2
            ),
    2 => array(
              "id" => 4,
              "parent" => 3
            ),
    3 => array(
              "id" => 5,
              "parent" => 3
            ),
    4 => array(
              "id" => 6,
              "parent" => 4
            ),
  );
```

Как из этого массива сформировать массив бинарного дерева через циклы? Не используя рекурсию и классы

Comment: `php` можно использовать?

Comment: бинарного дерева тут никакого нет, тебе наверное нужно построить древовидную структуру, по типу структуры каталога?

Comment: Да, как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Php нужно использовать, это же и есть php

Answer (score 1):

```
// в качестве таблицы БД просто массив
$elems = array(
    array( 'id' => 1, 'pid' => 0, 'title' => '1' ),
    array( 'id' => 2, 'pid' => 1, 'title' => '2' ),
    array( 'id' => 3, 'pid' => 1, 'title' => '3' ),
    array( 'id' => 4, 'pid' => 3, 'title' => '4' ),
    array( 'id' => 5, 'pid' => 0, 'title' => '5' ),
    array( 'id' => 6, 'pid' => 5, 'title' => '6' ),
    array( 'id' => 7, 'pid' => 5, 'title' => '7' ),
    array( 'id' => 8, 'pid' => 5, 'title' => '8' ),
    array( 'id' => 9, 'pid' => 0, 'title' => '9' ),
);

$links = array();
$tree = array();
for( $q = 0; $q < count( $elems ); $q++ )
{
    $elem = $elems[$q];   
    if( $elem['pid'] === 0 )
    {
        $tree[$elem['id']] = $elem;
        $links[$elem['id']] = &$tree[$elem['id']];
    }
    else
    {
        $links[$elem['pid']]['childrens'][$elem['id']] = $elem;
        $links[$elem['id']] = &$links[$elem['pid']]['childrens'][$elem['id']];
    }
}
```